# Counter-Strike AWP Quick Switch

Tags: macros, bind, autohotkey

I am trying to make a script where, when I press the mouse one time, it will wait 120 milliseconds, then double tab Q. The problem is when I make the bind hooked up to my mouse1 it is overriding Counter-Strike and it wont shoot. It just double taps Q. Can anyone help me?

```
Insert::

Suspend

Return

LButton::
Sleep, 1000
if (GetKeyState("LButton"))
Send, q
Sleep, 30
Send, q
```

Comment: What do you want `LButton`to do? Click or send `q`?

Answer (score 3):

I  believe that you still want counter strike to detect the mouse click also.
To do so, add a `~` in front of `LButton::`.
Result : `~LButton::`
`~` tells autohotkey to not block the hotkey's native function.
See more about Hotkey prefix symbols here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

Comment: Hey, not sure how else to respond to you; [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5691735) was rejected by others, but seems appropriate so I have added it myself. Thank you! Did not know about `ahkscript.org` before!

Comment: +1 Hmm, thanks for taking notice! Ahkscript.org is actually the new official website. Autohotkey.com is outdated, it gives old documentation with the old bug-riddled v1.0.48.05. I am actually an administrator at ahkscript.org. Cheers